# How to put quotes only on strings (not on numbers) in a VBA comma-separated list?

Tags: sql, vba, postgresql, excel

**Context :** I want to import in a PostgreSQL database some data that is in a Excel spreadsheet. 
To do so, I have established in VBA a connection with the database, and now, I want to carry out one INSERT SQL query for each of the rows, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('a','b',32,'d',17.2);
```

if we suppose a pgSQL table with 5 columns, 2 of them being numerical.

Using an array and the VBA `join` function I already figured out how to take a given line of the Excel table and convert it into a list **in which every item is quoted**, e.g.

```
('a','b','32','d','17.2');
```

from which I can easily write an SQL query.

The drawback of having all the items quoted is that upon inserting, the postgreSQL server will have to convert the numerical values that have been passed as strings back to numerical values again. I fear that this could impact performance, especially in situations where 50000+ lines need to be processed.

---

**The question :** In this context, I would like to **find a solution to put quotes only on non-numerical values when converting a VBA array into a comma-separated list** without using a For loop on the columns, which could affect performance as well.

My current VBA code to convert my horizontal Excel range into such a list is:

```vb
myArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(myRange.Value))
myList = "('" & Join(myArray, "','") & "')"
```

(in the above example, `myArray` would be a VBA array containing the values ("a","b",32,"d",17.2)).

Comment: When you load the array do put the `'` on the beginning and end of the text and not with the numbers then only use the `,` as the deliminator.

Comment: But if I do so, the strings will not be quoted at all, will they?

Comment: Please show how you load the array.

Comment: @ScottCraner I edited my question to show you how I convert my Excel horizontal range into an array, and then into a list.

Comment: I've got to ask why?, taking the quotes off the numbers is not going have much effect on performance,  maybe saves 20% network bandwidth, but the disk load on the server will be the same.

Comment: I have not begun to carry out these inserts yet (I will do it on Monday), but I am writing the VBA code now. I wondered about this potential issue just after writing the code but I have not tested it in practice yet.

Answer (score 4):

Take a few milli-seconds to convert the array before the Join.

```vb
Dim myarray As Variant, mylist As String, i As Long

myarray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("a1:f1").Value2))

For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
    If Not IsNumeric(myarray(i)) Then _
        myarray(i) = Chr(39) & Trim(myarray(i)) & Chr(39)
Next i

mylist = "(" & Join(myarray, Chr(44)) & ")"
Debug.Print mylist
```

Comment: I don't know what your numeric values look like beyond the simplified sample data. A better format mask might be `format(myarray(i), "general;'@'")`

Comment: Are we sure that the cost of doing this for each row will affect performance less than converting to string in VBA and then converting back to numerical after inserting in the database?

Comment: Since you are working on an in-memory array, the calculation time cost here is infinitesimal. I don't have your machine in front of me to perform time tests.

Comment: I will try doing it this way then.

Comment: I tried and it did not work, numbers still have quotes around them.

Comment: I tested this myself in the Immediate window; I'll go back and have another look.

Comment: The strings are not quoted at all and the non-integers numbers are rounded to integers with the "0;'@'" mask format. The other format you suggested didn't work out either.

Comment: The numbers are not quoted anymore, which is nice, but strangely enough, the quotes are put on the first character of each string instead of the whole string, meaning that Tokyo is transformed into 'T'okyo and not into 'Tokyo' as it should be.

Comment: I guess a format mask was the wrong approach. I've hard-coded in the wrapping `'` marks.

Comment: I guess a format mask was the wrong approach. I've hard-coded in the wrapping `'` marks.

Comment: Well, this for loop on the table columns is precisely what I wanted to avoid because it also consumes time, but I guess there is no other way. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It would only consume time if you did it while looping through the cells on the worksheet. Bulk loading the row data into an array and pre-processing the array is significantly different. This is why we bulk load large data matrixes into a variant array and process them there before returning the array *en masse* to the worksheet.

Comment: btw, if you are interested in performance, why are you inserting individual rows instead of a bulk insert to sql?

Comment: Well, I could copy my data into a csv file and then use the PostgreSQL command COPY, that's right. But this command only works from the server, which means the macro would not work from another machine (in practice the database is stored in my company's server and the clients that will run the macro are the employees).

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop with a buffer to build the SQL. You won't notice a difference on the performance. You'll also have more control over the type and you'll be able to escape the quote in case a string contains one:

```vb
Sub Test()
  Dim data()
  data = [{ "a",1 ; "b",2 }]
  Debug.Print ToSqlInsert("MyTable (Col1, Col2)", data)
End Sub


Public Function ToSqlInsert(target As String, data()) As String
  Dim sb() As String, n As Long, r As Long, c As Long
  ReDim sb(0 To UBound(data, 1) * UBound(data, 2) * 2)

  sb(n) = "INSERT INTO " & target & " VALUES ("
  n = n + 1

  For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
      If c > 1 Then sb(n - 1) = ","

      Select Case VBA.VarType(data(r, c))
        Case vbString:  sb(n) = "'" & Replace$(data(r, c), "'", "''") & "'"
        Case vbDate:    sb(n) = Int((data(r, c) - #1/1/1970#) * 86400) ' to epoche '
        Case vbEmpty:   sb(n) = "NULL"
        Case Else:      sb(n) = data(r, c)
      End Select

      n = n + 2
    Next

    sb(n - 1) = "),("
  Next

  sb(n - 1) = ");"
  ToSqlInsert = Join$(sb, Empty)
End Function
```